# Adobe Flash Player is Installed But It can not be found by other applications

Tags: windows-7, flash-player

I have installed adobe flash player active X, but none of applications can detect it. for example if an application needs flash player it will show an error that it is not installed, sometimes ago everything was fine, but it is about one week that I have faced this issue.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Close all browsers and in **Task Manager**'s *Processes* tab, ensure no Flash process is active (or just reboot)
2. Download and run the [Flash uninstaller](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/uninstall-flash-player-windows.html)
3. Reboot
4. Go to [this page](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/), select **Windows 7** in *Step 1*, **Internet Explorer** in *Step 2*, uncheck the option to install Chrome, download **install_flashplayer11x32ax_gtbd_chrd_dn_aih.exe** and run it

   [image: 1]
5. If you have Firefox, Safari or Opera installed, repeat step #4 but obviously this time select **Other Browsers** and download and run **install_flashplayer11x32_gtbd_chrd_dn_aih.exe** instead
6. Open each browser and check on [this page](http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/) whether you have the latest Flash version installed successfully
7. Check the other apps to see if your problem's fixed

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have installed Flash Plugin, which is not the same as Flash ActiveX. Start Internet Explorer and visit http://get.adobe.com/flash to install Flash ActiveX.

Comment: No I have installed all of them, the player, the ActiveX and the plug-in. On My Laptop everything is ok, on my PC everything was OK too, but it is about one week I have this issue, I have tried uninstalling and re-installing it, but nothing happened.

Comment: @Stranger what's the app that doesn't detect Flash?

Comment: every app that needs Flash!!!

Comment: Sounds to me like you're trying to watch videos from one those "watch ... online free" sites, or from some kids shady pay-per-click page. In either case the flash popup would be little more than a black-SEO money making scam. If youtube videos work, and annoying flashing ads on the sides of websites work, then you have flash.

Comment: @Stranger please give us an example, there aren't many apps that require Flash. Actually the only one I could think of is Steam, but it's using Trident engine, so if it works in IE, then it also works in Steam.
Another thing that comes to my mind is that you're using 64-bit apps, those won't work with 32-bit Flash.

Comment: For example Demo Builder,Bullrushsoft swf to exe, GOM player for playing swf files, Flash Digger and so on. All of them will show an error that Flash player is not installed :(

Answer (score 1):

here is a possible solution.

http://bitc.bme.emory.edu/~lzhou/blogs/?p=337

The folder C:\WINDOWS\system32\Macromed was locked by explorer.exe.