# Black box instead of youtube embed flash

Tags: windows-7, firefox, youtube, adobe-flash

I am expirencing a very strang issue. All (or almost all) youtube videos embeded using IFRAME (much [like on this page](http://news.yahoo.com/blogs/lookout/footage-russia-meteor-highlights-chaos-confusion-151744816.html)) show themselves as black boxes in my Firefox. All other videos (like the first you on said page) show themselves normally, and I also can watch any of the videos from black boxes on youtube, if I figure out the path.
I use folowing script (run in youtube iframe) to try to find the video:

```
location.href="http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query="+encodeURIComponent(document.title.substr(0,document.title.length-10));
```

1. How do I fix my firefox?
2. Is there a better way to find out path to embeded video?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Does the same page look ok on other browsers? Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling Flash? (Follow the steps mentioned [here](http://superuser.com/a/550327/138343)).

Comment: I tried to reinstal flash.

Answer (score 2):

What solved this issue for me was the following:

1.Go to [you tube](http://youtube.com), click on `share`, then on `embed` and copy the `<iframe> code` into your `source code` in the editor you are using to `upload posts`.

2.Your code will look something like this:

```
iframe width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/noeGMUOjePQ" 

  frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe
```

(i had to remove the tags, because it wouldn't show up my comment)

3.Now, at the end of the URL, which is this part: `src="//www.youtube.com/embed/noeGMUOjePQ"` add `?rel=0`
So it will look like this:

```
src="//www.youtube.com/embed/noeGMUOjePQ?rel=0"
```

4.Save

This might solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I might be able to give you an answer to your second question. 
Click the share button under the video; then click the second tab out of the row. It bwill give you a frame to embed your video.

Comment: My friend, do you see the screenshot? Well, if you do, I'm really sure you do NOT see any button. That is the problem. Flash does not load at all.